# File download scanning with modsecurity

Tags: apache, mod-security, mod-security2

I want to scan the file downloads with mod-security. Is it possible to do this? I could not find any way of doing it. File upload scanning is feasible but how to do scanning of downloads?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible to do this.

Look at [SecResponseBodyAccess](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecResponseBodyAccess) and [SecResponseMimeType](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecResponseBodyMimeType). Note however that only text files are really useful to check. PDFs and other documents which contain binary data lead to many false positives.

Comment: Thanks, but the same issue should be for uploads also?